# React/Redux component with checkboxes does not update when click on checkbox

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my component I have checkboxes. When I click on them I want save selected checkbox in redux state and update my component so selected checkbox should shown as checked.
So this is my component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {selectIngredient} from '../actions';
class Ingredient extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.isSelected = this.isSelected.bind(this);
        this.handleCheckbox = this.handleCheckbox.bind(this);

    }


    handleCheckbox(e) {
        const value=e.target.value;
        this.props.selectIngredient(value);
    }


    isSelected(id) {
        return (this.props.selectedIngredients.indexOf(id) > -1)
     }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="form-check checkbox">
                    <label className="form-check-label">
                        <input checked={this.isSelected(1)}
                               className="form-check-input"
                               onClick={this.handleCheckbox}
                               type="checkbox" value="1" />
                        1
                    </label>

                </div>
                <div className="form-check checkbox">
                    <label className="form-check-label">
                        <input checked={this.isSelected(2)}
                               className="form-check-input"
                               onClick={this.handleCheckbox}
                               type="checkbox" value="2" />
                        2
                    </label>

                </div>
                <div className="form-check checkbox">
                    <label className="form-check-label">
                        <input checked={this.isSelected(3)}
                               className="form-check-input"
                               onClick={this.handleCheckbox}
                               type="checkbox" value="3" />
                       3
                    </label>

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
    const {selectedIngredients} = state;
    return {selectedIngredients}

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{selectIngredient})(Ingredient);
```

And this is action/index.js

```
import {SELECT_INGREDIENT} from "../constants";

export function selectIngredient(selected){
    const action = {
        type: SELECT_INGREDIENT,
        selected
    }
    return action;
}
```

And here is reducer:

```
import {SELECT_INGREDIENT} from "../constants";

export default (state={selectedIngredients:[]}, action)=>{
    let stateBefore = Object.assign({},state);
    switch(action.type){
        case SELECT_INGREDIENT:
            const {selected} = action;
            stateBefore['selectedIngredients'].push(+selected);
            return stateBefore

        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

When I click on checkboxes nothing changes, they stay empty. Component is not updating. But redux updating its state.
I thought if redux state is updating so should the component and its checkboxes. Is it wrong?

Please help me figure out how to make this work. Thank you

---

**The answer given in the comments below:**

in your reducer return { ...state, selectedIngredients: [...state.selectedIngredients, action.selected] }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a mutation:**

```
  let stateBefore = Object.assign({},state);
  ...
      stateBefore['selectedIngredients'].push(+selected);
```

> You are shallowly copying the state object but you still mutate the
>   selectedIngredients because it is copied by reference so you are still
>   modifying the existing selectedIngredients object.

Check the first answer to following issue https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1769

**use object spread operator:**

```
case SELECT_INGREDIENT:
  return {
    ...state, 
    selectedIngredients: [...state.selectedIngredients, action.selected],
  }
```

Comment: thank you. I'm actually using component state approach before, but now trying to move it to redux

Comment: I thought if redux state is updating so should the component and its checkboxes.

Comment: try not mutating state as referenced in this issue https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/585

Comment: in your reducer return { ...state, selectedIngredients: [...state.selectedIngredients, action.selected] }

Comment: I use stateBefore = Object.assign({},state); to clone state and then work with this new object..is this still mutating ?

Comment: Is any chance you can explain why Object.assign({},state) didn't do the trick ?